# Unity: How to Raycast in a 360 VR video?

Tags: unity, raycasting, virtual-reality, 360-video

I have set up a basic inverted sphere in unity and am running a 360 video inside it and it is working fine in VR. But i want to raycast inside that video to show information about some objects which are shown in the video.

Is that possible? If yes then i should i go about it?

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/interaction-vr?playlist=22946

This article says that i need three scripts for it: VREyeRaycaster, VRInput, and VRInteractiveItem

I have seen some people do it on Youtube and I suppose they put 3D objects in their videos behind the objects they want to highlight and then they raycast.

i want to create a virtual tour of some places, the videos of which i will shoot in 360 and import in unity. i have already set up my inverted sphere and a sample video running on it. then i want to pause the video at certain points and show information about some objects on clicks by user.

Comment: Can you describe your desired outcome here? What do you want your raycast to tell you? "You clicked on Latitude 43.2 Longitude 163.7" you can get with just a little math. "You clicked on a part of the video showing a bird" would require some mark-up on your part to track where clickable objects are at each moment of the video. Is your question about how to create that mark-up (eg. animating colliders to match up with the video)? I show an [example of mapping spherical raycasts to a 2D UI in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/140705/39518), in case that may be of use.

Comment: yeah how can i create those markers in the 360 videos? using empty game objects? and will they move with the video? since its a video and not a set of objects i can't really track what is happening inside it.
once the raycast detects that marker i can easily pause the video at that time and do what i want and resume again.

Comment: Will the gameobjects automatically know what part of the video to follow? No, you have to tell them what you want them to do. Try showing an example of what kind of video features you want to track, and update your question to focus on authoring these markers rather than the raycasting (once you have colliders in your scene to shoot at, the raycasting part doesn't need any special-case handling)

Comment: i want to create a virtual tour of some places, the videos of which i will shoot in 360 and import in unity. i have already set up my inverted sphere and a sample video running on it.
then i want to pause the video at certain points and show information about some object.

Comment: Don't tell me here in the comments, edit the question. Ideally include some example frames. so we have an idea of the size of the objects and how they move through the view.