# Create a curved UI

Tags: unity, gui

I am new and Unity and I want to do a curved UI as if I project a canvas on a cylinder, a bit like this : [picture](http://l3apq3bncl82o596k2d1ydn1-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/unity-Curved-UI-by-Chisely.png)
Thing is, it is not that easy. I found [this question and answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/140705/), but didn't manage to make it worked: I am stuck at stage 5 & 6.

In step 5 in don't understand the all step. I created a sphere which is center on my camera. This camera has a shader which flip the normal but the last part but I don't get this part "maps the assigned RenderTexture around its surface using latitude & longitude (equirectangular mapping)

If you have more details explanation or even a example scene I would be grateful.

I had export the package : https://github.com/QuentinACN/CurvedUI

Comment: The more detail you can give us about what you're trying to do (eg. the particular shape of the UI you want), and where you're stuck (what specifically about step 5 or 6 you don't understand or need help with), the better we can target answers to what you need.

Comment: Well I am trying to do a curved UI as if I project a canvas on a cylinder, a bit like this : http://l3apq3bncl82o596k2d1ydn1-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/unity-Curved-UI-by-Chisely.png

In step 5 in don't understand the all step.
I created a sphere which is center on my camera. This camera has a shader which flip the normal but the last part but I don't get this part "maps the assigned RenderTexture around its surface using latitude & longitude (equirectangular mapping)

Comment: Can you give us more info about what you mean "I am stuck"? Did you not understand something? Do you not know how to do something? The more details you give, the more information we have to help you. Add the new info in your question (instead of in comments)

Comment: That part of step 5 just means that the texture is displayed on the mesh the way you want it. In my example, I wanted to wrap the texture around the sphere using the x coordinate as longitude and the y coordinate as latitude. In your example for a cylinder, the default UV unwrap on the cylinder is probably all you need. Does it not look the way you want yet?

Comment: I think I don't get the way I want cause I juste wanted to reproduce what you have done but without success.

Comment: Please upload images and code to your question, using the tools offered in the edit bar, instead of posting links to external resources. They are exposed to [link rot](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2720/where-should-i-upload-resources-linked-to-my-question-answer) and make your question harder to understand.

Comment: Ok I tried with GitHub

Comment: Hello,
By any chance @DMGregory do you have an package of the curve interface you did for the post I referred ?
Thx

Comment: That version works with a sphere, but it sounds like you want a cylinder. A package of my spherical solution won't help you.

Comment: Hello,
Well for now i wanted to see how you deal with this problematic with a sphere and afrer try some other thing.