# World Canvas InputField cursor precision/control from RenderTexture output in Overlay UI

Tags: unity, camera, spaces, unity-ui

How do you have a world canvas input field cursor be controllable from the input being mapped from a UI overlay with its raw image supplied from render texture from a render camera?

Described another way:

World Canvas Input Field -> Render Camera creates renderTexture for -> Screen Overlay UI Raw Texture -> Main Camera

How do you have the cursor position be mapped from the Screen Overlay UI Raw Texture?

Comment: How did you end up in this predicament? Are you sure your setup can't be restructured?

Comment: [I think you can use the technique shown in this answer to map the input from your source space into your texture space](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/140705/39518). Your coordinate system won't be a sphere like in that example, but the same strategy should apply.