# Dynamic UI Canvas on Mesh

Tags: unity, 3d, shaders, mesh, image

I have dynamically generated images in WorldSpace Canvas and I need to put them somehow on shield that crashes. Is it possible tu put that canvas on mesh shader texture or render it on texture?

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you for advice.

Comment: [Have you tried the method described in this previous Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/140334/39518)? Where have you run into trouble rendering your UI to a texture and displaying that texture on your mesh?

Comment: I didn't try this metod. Thanks for advice.